# Lambda expression to select attribute in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I have an XML like this -

```
<root>
   <child at1="1Dragon" at2="2">
      ...
   </child>
</root>
```

I want to query the attribute at1 and check if it has 1 in the string. For that I have written this lambda expression -

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(my_xml);
bool test = xml.Descendants("child").Attributes("at1").ToString().Contains("1");
```

Now this does not give me the desired result. The attributes list does have at1 and at2 but how can i query them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this part of your query returns an enumerable of the attributes on child nodes, matching the name "at1".

```
xml.Descendants("child").Attributes("at1")
```

Calling ToString on this invokes the default ToString implementation for the IEnumerable, which is not what you want. You need to invoke a LINQ extension method to traverse the attributes and check whether the value of any of the attributes match. `Any` seems like a good match:

```
bool test = xml.Descendants("child").Attributes("at1").Any(attribute => 
    attribute.Value.Contains("1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant as `Attributes("at1").ToString();` return a string that represents  the current object which is an `IEnumerable<string>` litteraly returned

if you have Only one `Child` you  can do something  like this

```
 bool testVallue = xml.Descendants("child").Attributes("at1").FirstOrDefault().Value.Contains("1");
```

if  you want all attributes of all childs  just  do this

```
var  allVallue = xml.Descendants("child").Attributes("at1").Where(att => att.Value.Contains("1")); 
//you can  then check 
        if (allVallue.Any())
        {

        }
```